# How can a WCF Service obtain Query Parameters?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, azure, query-string

I'm working on an Azure service for a Windows Phone app. I need the Azure Service to access the users' OneDrive. Following this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243649.aspx), my scenario should be:

- The user sign in to Windows Live on the WP app.
- The Live web service sends the authorization code to a redirect URI that I defined, with the code appended as a query parameter named code, as:
  http://www.example.com/callback.php?code=2bd12503-7e88-bfe7-c5c7-82274a740ff
- I get the authorization code and access the users' data

After investigating a lot in Service, I still can't find a way to capture the query parameter in my web service. As I am new to this area, I don't know where to focus on. I'll be really appreciated if you can give my an advise or answer my following questions:

1. Can I access the service just using the url with parameter in a browser? How can I see if the service is working properly?
2. An article mentioned using WCF [Web Get] attribute to get Query Parameters, but I still don't know how to implement both the IService1.cs and Service1.cs file, could you give me a sample about how to access the value of Query Parameter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand your problem properly but if you want your RESTfull WCF service to be the callback receiver for the request code, your Service must be hosted with a WebHttpBinding and a ServiceContract similar to this one.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "callback?code={requestCode}")]
    void OAuthCallback(string requestCode);
}
```

So if the base address of your Service is "http://service.mydomain.com/MyService.svc" the OAuthCallback Method will be called when a http GET request to "http://service.mydomain.com/MyService.svc/callback?code=RequestCode" is made.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer makes me clear. But what's the proper way to test this service? Can I simply visit "http://service.mydomain.com/MyService.svc/callback?code=RequestCode" in the browser, or should I write another service host? Thanks !!!

Comment: Sure. You can use the browser, or any tool that can create a simple http get. Fiddler, wget, browser,... You could also use WCF to test your service. If you create a channel with ChannelFactory<IService> and webhttpbinding the call will be invoked as a http get matching the uri template.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your help is really important for me, a beginner : ) Pity that I don't have enough reputation to vote you up.